# Install gem for Java application on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, rubygems

How do you install gems when running a Java application (Play! 2.0) on Heroku?

Creating a `Gemfile` file makes Heroku think it is a Ruby application and does not start the application.

Installing from `heroku run bash` fails due to missing permission to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1.

Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a single app that uses multiple buildpacks using buildpack-multi: https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi/tree/2a4cefc75ffb33a8196f84a9189801bb0a0b8eea